# AS2 AttachMovie from loaded swf movie

Tags: actionscript-2

i'm facing one problem about attaching movieclip from loaded movie, so basically we have a Map

```
Map.loadMovie("SimpleMap.swf");
```

in this map there's a npc dialogue with its name "Dialogue1" I want to attach it to the client. It should be basically something like

```
_root.attachMovie("Map.Dialogue1", "dialogue", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
```

but it seems I can't get it to work. Anyone can help?
Note: Also I want to attach the movieclip to the client instead of the map, else I would use Map.attachMovie

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since I wrote any Actionscript 2 stuff, but have you tried removing the quotes around Map.Dialogue1 ? - If I remember correctly passing a string would make Flash look for the symbol in the library, not from the global or current scope...

```
_root.attachMovie(Map.Dialogue1, "dialogue", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can import mx.core.UIObject and then use the method _root.createObject()  (or if it is O-O use createClassObject()).

It is going to attach the "npc dialog" as an object... you need to specify the linkage name and give the instance a name.  So for example if you called the dialog "npc_dialog" in the library then use:

_root.createObject("npc_dialog", "my_npc", _root.getNextHighestDepth());

Answer (score 0):

Here is something else you can try... go to the library and drag a instance of the movie onto the stage somewhere where it will not be seen, like for instance on the next key frame or off the stage then try to run attachMovie().

What happens is flash will compile the clip in the most efficient way possible so if it sees you imported a package but did not use it then it will ignore this class in the compiled clip... so when you go to run and it tries to attach the movie it can't find it.